# C: Trying to implement a dual-pivot quicksort but getting stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: c, infinite-loop, quicksort

Prior to writing this I have tried to find an example of the algorithm implemented in C but couldn't find one after searching on google for a while. Though it is possible that I'm not versed enough in programming terms to search for it correctly. This code is based on the paper about the algorithm (example in Java) and another implementation in Java that I found.

It is currently stuck in an infinite loop but I have trouble finding the cause. Part of that is probably because I tried to convert the code to C but made mistakes.

```html
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int A[], int size) {
    printf("[ ");
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d", A[i]);
        if (i < size - 1) printf(", ");
    }
    printf(" ]\n");
}

void quickSort(int A[], int left, int right) {
    if (right <= left ) return;

    int temp;

    if (A[right] < A[left]) {
        temp = A[right];
        A[right] = A[left];
        A[left] = temp;
    }

    int pLow = left + 1;
    int pHigh = right - 1;
    int i = left + 1;

    while (i <= pHigh) {
        if (A[i] < A[pLow]) {
            temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[pLow];
            A[pLow] = temp;
            A[pLow++];
            i++;
        }
        else if (A[pHigh] < A[i]) {
            temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[pHigh];
            A[pHigh] = temp;
            A[pHigh--];
        }
        else i++;
    }

    temp = A[left];
    A[left] = A[--pLow];
    A[pLow] = temp;
    temp = A[right];
    A[right] = A[++pHigh];
    A[pHigh] = temp;

    quickSort(A, left, pLow-1);
    if (A[pLow] < A[pHigh]) quickSort(A, pLow+1, pHigh-1);
    quickSort(A, pHigh+1, right);
}

int main() {
    int size = 10;
    int array[10] = {1, 0, 7, 9, 6, 2, 5, 8, 4, 3};

    printf("Before: ");
    printArray(array, size);

    quickSort(array, 0, size-1);

    printf("After: ");
    printArray(array, size);

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is pretty suspicious ...

```
int pLow = left + 1;
int pHigh = right - 1;
```

... when you have just gone to the trouble to ensure that `A[left] < A[right]`, but have done nothing to test or fix the relative order of `A[left + 1]` and `A[right - 1]`.  I think you want to choose the pivots from the very ends of the subarray:

```
int pLow = left;
int pHigh = right;
```

More significantly, though, you have no termination condition for your recursion.  Your `quickSort()` function should terminate without doing anything (especially without recursing) when `right <= left`.

**Update:**

Although I would not implement it quite like this myself, the following represents the smallest change I could come up with to transform the starting code into a working sort:

```
void quickSort(int A[], int left, int right) {
    int temp;

    if (right <= left) return;

    if (A[right] < A[left]) {
        temp = A[right];
        A[right] = A[left];
        A[left] = temp;
    }
    /* A[left] and A[right] are the left and right pivot values */

    int pLow = left + 1;
    int pHigh = right - 1;
    int i = left + 1;

    while (i <= pHigh) {
        if (A[i] < A[left]) {
            temp = A[i];
            A[i++] = A[pLow];
            A[pLow++] = temp;
        }
        else if (A[right] < A[i]) {
            temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[pHigh];  /* i not incremented here */
            A[pHigh--] = temp;
        }
        else i++;
    }

    temp = A[left];
    A[left] = A[--pLow];
    A[pLow] = temp;
    temp = A[right];
    A[right] = A[++pHigh];
    A[pHigh] = temp;

    quickSort(A, left, pLow - 1);
    if (A[pLow] < A[pHigh]) quickSort(A, pLow + 1, pHigh - 1);
    quickSort(A, pHigh + 1, right);
}
```

Note in particular that the two swaps after the end of the loop make sense only if the pivot values are maintained until then in `A[left]` and `A[right]`.  That means, however, that the comparisons in the inner loop must be with *those* values, not with `A[pLow]` and `A[pHigh]`.

I left the original initializations for `pLow` and `pHigh` (my earlier comments notwithstandiing); consequently, these represent the indices of the *next available* positions in the low and high partitions.  I also changed some of the increments and decrements.

Comment: Hmm. The first part you point out is part of the paper on the dual pivot quicksort here http://iaroslavski.narod.ru/quicksort/DualPivotQuicksort.pdf (page 9, upper part). That's why I have it like that. 

As for the missing termination condition... oh god. Not quite sure how I missed that part but it's fixed now. Infinite loop is gone, but the code does not output a sorted array yet: `Before: [ 1, 0, 7, 9, 6, 2, 5, 8, 4, 3 ]
After: [ 3, 0, 1, 9, 3, 2, 5, 8, 9, 3 ] ` That does not change no matter whether I implement your former suggestion or not.

Comment: You also have an apparent error in this line: `A[left] = A[++pHigh]` ; I'm pretty sure you should be setting `A[right]` at that point.  That's not the only remaining error.

Comment: In your inner loop you are not performing proper swaps because you modify the array indices in the middle of the job.  Furthermore, at several places in the tail end of the function, you appear to use increment or decrement operators where you really want plain `+ 1` or `- 1`.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. I have worked over the code in the sections you specified. The part I'm not 100% sure about is whether I all handle the indices correctly yet. I edited my initial post with the current code.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working version of the sort.

Comment: Thank you so much! Looks like I jumbled my variables quite badly there. I went through your code and fixed mine along the way and it works now. Awesome!